# How to break when an event occurs, or determine associated handlers?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I'm using a large open-source control and I can't seem to find the code that handles a double-click event. Could I perhaps have the debugger break when a double-click occurs or otherwise learn what code is associated with that event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I stumbled around until I found the code I was looking for.

BTW, before the DoubleClick event occurs, a MouseDown event occurs for the second click, with MouseEventArgs.Clicks == 2.

Answer (score 0):

The event you're probably looking for is [Control.MouseDoubleClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedoubleclick.aspx), which is raised whenever a control is double-clicked by the mouse. Or, if you're deriving from Control, you can override [OnMouseDoubleClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onmousedoubleclick.aspx).